# Creating a liferay portlet using spring roo

Tags: spring, liferay, spring-roo

Does Spring Roo supports creating a liferay portlet built out of JSP/Primefaces scaffolding.

Thanks!

Pratik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plan to support portlet development with Roo.

But, you can find an [add-on here](http://code.google.com/p/spring-roo-addon-portletmvc/) that allow your Roo project to turn into a Spring MVC Portlet project so that it will be complient with the portlet specification.

Comment: This addon never completed! is there any other way?